# Как скомпилировать консольное приложение VB.NET в Linux?

Tags: linux, компиляция, vb.net, .net-core, mono

Есть несложный код консольного приложения на VB.NET. В нём используются коллекции, регулярные выражения, поиск и чтение файлов из файловой системы и вывод на консоль. 
Ничего специфического для VB.NET нет. Всё использованное есть в стандартном C#, думаю в .NET Core - тоже.

В Windows компилируется так:

```
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" || exit 2

for /d %%f in (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*, %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v*) do if exist %%f\vbc.exe set vbc="%%f\vbc.exe"
if "%vbc%"=="" goto novbc
echo Compiler: %vbc%

%vbc% /debug- /optimize+ /imports:System.Collections.Generic /imports:System.Text /imports:System.Text.RegularExpressions /imports:System.Diagnostics /imports:System.IO *.vb

goto end

:novbc
color c
echo No one VB.NET compiler was found
color
exit 2

:end
```

Как скомпилировать и запустить программу в Linux?

Comment: @0xdb, лучше было на [tag:.net-core] исправить - я, похоже, по нему промахнулся, когда выбирал. Он тут потому что я предполагаю, что можно как core скомпилировать.

Comment: @0andriy, а разве моно умеет компилировать исходник на VB.NET?

Comment: @0andriy, запускать я давно сам пробовал - работало (даже WinForms). А скомпилировать-то как? Хотя, кажется гугл говорит, что тоже можно, но что-то нормальный гайд найти не могу - что ставить и какими командами компилить.

Comment: @0andriy, компилятор надо компилировать из исходников? Готового нет?

Answer (score 2):

Например, в дистрибутиве Debian имеются такие пакеты: `mono-basic-source` и `mono-vbnc`. Последний — это Visual Basic Compiler & Runtime. 
Пробуем следующий код:

```vb
Imports System

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter Key to Exit.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Собираем:

```sh
$ vbnc hw.vb 
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 (Mono 4.0.1 - tarball)
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

Assembly 'hw, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' saved successfully to '.../hw.exe'.
Compilation successful
Compilation took 00:00:00.5613440
```

И запускаем:

```sh
$ mono hw.exe
Hello World!
Press Enter Key to Exit.
```

Comment: Спасибо, вечером попробую!

Comment: Попробовал. Не работает. Точнее работает, но поддержка синтаксиса ограниченная и нет linq. Похоже, ideone использует тот же vbnc: https://ideone.com/KBqnQD - можно это скомпилировать? Ещё в пакете есть vbnc2, но он в принципе не хочет работать: `vbnc2 hello.vb 
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 (Mono 4.0.1 - tarball)
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

vbnc : Command line : error VBNC2017: The library 'Accessibility.dll' could not be found.
There were 1 errors and 0 warnings.
Compilation took 00:00:00.0828430`